# Sharing an excel workbook renders VBA unviewable and conditional formatting uneditable

Tags: vba, excel

After creating a workbook and writing a macro in the "Module" window, the macro is assigned to a button. Protecting the workbook by clicking Review > "Protect Shared Workbook" renders the entire VBA project of that workbook "unviewable", the exact error message is "Project is Unviewable". In addition the Conditional Formatting button is grayed-out.

Unprotecting the workbook and sharing it with the option "allow changes by one or more..." ticked has no effect.

The macro still functions but I would like to be able to remedy the "Project is Unviewable" issue.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is the answer to your question.
[image]

So, there it is, the VBA project becomes read-only when you share the workbook. I sincerely doubt there is a work-around for this one.

Comment: If it becomes read-only upon sharing I'd think/hope there'd be a way to undo it.

Comment: I hope so too, but I could not figure out a way back into the VBA project afterward. It would not let me in no matter what I tried.

Answer (score 0):

Since all you need to do is copy data from another workbook, I'd suggest you take a different approach. You can ditch the macro and add the information from the other workbook into your spreadsheet as an external data source. Then you can simply right-click > refresh. This should also ensure that your conditional formatting remains intact.

Remember, after you insert the external data, you need to do a couple more things to make sure that you do not get prompted for the file name on refresh, that the import does not cause disruptive shifts, and formulas adjacent to the external data are copied down.

Click on properties

[image]

Then set the options as so. If you would like, you can also preserve column width.

[image]

Last, if you need to change the path to the file problematically, find out the name of the data range and then you can use code similar to the following in the "ThisWorkbook" module to change it and then refresh the data.

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheet1.Range("test").QueryTable.Connection = "TEXT;" & PATHTOFILE
    Sheet1.Range("test").QueryTable.Refresh
End Sub
```

Comment: I looked into that but never understood if it would fit my purpose. The point is that I am exporting a table from an external program/site as a CSV file. And I need to import that table, however the number of rows/items of that table varies with each export.

Comment: It would not matter. You can use a CSV or a table in a worksheet interchangeably. When the external data source updates, if there are more or less rows in it, the size of the range will update as well. The only thing you need to do is make sure the csv file name always stays the same... or you could run a macro when the workbook opens to update the reference for the external data so that it automatically points to a new CSV.

Comment: To import a CSV go to data > from text > choose file, and then follow the steps.

Comment: FYI, after importing the table, you can extend the range that hold the data to encompass any columns you have that include formulas. If you do that, then once you update the table, if there are more or less rows, then the formulas will copy up/down as well.

Comment: That sort of works - the problem is that each time I "refresh" I have to click the import workbook again, which is a hassle, I would have preferred it to be much more streamlined. In any event, I am curious to the solution of my original problem.

Comment: It asks you that only because you need to set the options so that it does not ask each time. By default it will, but you can set it so that it does not.

Comment: Any luck? The approach I gave you is the easiest and least buggy way of doing what you asked.

Comment: Yes, thank you, what you described *is* an idea and importing a connection with disabled filename prompt does work for me, however it is not an answer to my question, simply a workaround. Thank you, none the less!